# Sort list of list of String numbers in Python3?

Tags: python, sorting

```
test_list = [['10','fff'], ['11','dfhg'], ['3','zszszs'], ['4','ll'], ['18','kds']]
test_list.sort()

for line in test_list:
    print(line)
```

This code sorts the list like this:

```
['10', 'fff']
['11', 'dfhg']
['18', 'kds']
['3', 'zszszs']
['4', 'll']
```

But I need to sort it in numeric order like this:

```
['3', 'zszszs']
['4', 'll']
['10', 'fff']
['11', 'dfhg']
['18', 'kds']
```

I have already tried the `.sorted()` function and `itemgetter`, none of these works.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort list of lists by highest number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30076145/how-to-sort-list-of-lists-by-highest-number)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the key argument for sort, will give a customized sort

```
test_list = [['10','fff'], ['11','dfhg'], ['3','zszszs'], ['4','ll'], ['18','kds']]

test_list.sort(key=lambda x: int(x[0]))

for line in test_list:
    print(line)
```